# angular.js - update `ng-model` with text.value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a `javascript` event to update `input value` dynamically

```
var posx = event.target.querySelector('input.posx');
          posx.value = event.dx;
```

Which it works to update the `html`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="posx"  size="30" placeholder="x" class="post">
```

but somehow it did not update the `ng-model="post`. When I `console.log($scope.posx);`, I get

> undefined

What seems to be the problem here

Comment: Did you try doing a scope.apply after you change the variable? You would need to apply the scope after you change some variable outside of angular (e.g. using jquery).

Comment: How should I call `$scope.apply()`? I am using `interact.js` to drag around a `<div>` and update the position X and Y when drag end. I a, not sure how to trigger `angularjs` from different `js` file.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Show full angular context. It's really not the proper angular way to do things. Also what is `posx`? That doesn't look like angular scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can be executed in Javascript context,

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('posx')[0];
var scope = angular.element(e).scope();
scope.posx = "updated value";
scope.$digest();
```

OR

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('posx')[0];
angular.element(e).triggerHandler('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.posx = event.target.querySelector('input.posx');
          $scope.posx.value = event.dx;
```

try with `$scope`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.